# destroying object in vector when new object added

Tags: c++

When push_back method of vector is called the previous object in the vector is getting destroyed  what might be the reason for this.

```
template<typename type> void SomeList<type>::AddElement(type &inObject)
{
    pList.push_back(inObject);// pList is member of my class Vector SomeList 
}
```

Comment: Some code, please. Vectors don't normally do that, so some context is needed before anyone can help you.

Comment: @Marcelos have edited the query with code

Comment: In the future, highlight your code and click the `101010` button to format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector doesn't destroy the object. It replaces it.

For example:

```
vector< A> myVector; // Do some initialization, etc.
A myNewObject;
myVector[0] = myNewObject; // Replace the object.
```

That means the assignment operator (A`& A::operator=( const A&)`) will be called for `myVector[0]`. There is no destruction there.

The destruction is done when the vector itself is destructed, or when the memory is reallocated (in this case, the copy constructor is also used, to copy the objects from the old location to the new location, before destroying the old ones).

**Later edit**
In push_back case, the destruction must be determined by a reallocation.

Comment: @Catalin: ok then in my code when i called AddElement method, while calling push_back it internally calls destroy method.

Comment: Exactly, but not for each push_back call, only when reallocation should be made.

Comment: Ok, ya thats right, but does it mean that the objects in the vector are destroyed.

Comment: @Catalin OK, i got it even if it calls destroy method. the objects are not destroyed. when i check the total number of objects are consistent, Any way thanx for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It might not be that the object is "destroyed" per se but rather that during reallocation to increase the vector size the object gets copied with the old one being cleaned up.  Hence, it is not a good idea to put in something where creation and destruction control program flow.  For that I'd suggest another container object or `smart_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you post some code, we'll have a much better chance of helping you.  FYI, `vector::push_back` might cause a reallocation of the internal array so it can grow.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

> When push_back method of vector is called the previous object in the vector is getting destroyed. What might be the reason for this.

The reason is that `std::vector` is specified thus.

When you keep adding elements to the vector, at some point its memory capacity is used up. It then allocates a new memory reserve, copies all the old object to there (plus the one you're adding when it happens), and destroys the old objects.
`std::vector` tries to minimize this by "over-allocating", it allocates more memory than required to anticipate further growth. (Look for `capacity()` vs. `size()` and `reserve()` vs. `resize()` to learn more about this.) But every reserve might at some point be exceeded, and then it has to re-allocate and copy.

If you don't want this, have a look at `std::deque` of `std::list`.